# Racket xexpr not work for numbers less than 9

Tags: xml, racket

I am trying to save some data in XML file, and I used the Racket library for that.

I got some strange behavior. When I enter:

```
> (xexpr->string '(elements () (INTEGER-CONSTANT () 9)))
;=>
"<elements><INTEGER-CONSTANT>&#9;</INTEGER-CONSTANT></elements>"
```

But when I change 9 to 8, I get:

```
> (xexpr->string '(elements () (INTEGER-CONSTANT () 8)))
. . xexpr->string: contract violation
  Not an Xexpr. Expected a string, symbol, valid numeric entity, comment, processing instruction, or list, given 8
Context:
'(elements () (INTEGER-CONSTANT () 8))
  in: the 1st argument of
      (-> xexpr? string?)
  contract from: 
      <collects>/xml/private/xexpr.rkt
  blaming: FILE_PATH
  at: <collects>/xml/private/xexpr.rkt:100.2
```

Why is this happen? What is the difference between 8 and 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://docs.racket-lang.org/xml/index.html?q=xexpression#%28def._%28%28lib._xml/main..rkt%29._valid-char~3f%29%29) 8 is not allowed, and 9 is. To me it looks like it is being interpreted as a Unicode character because it's being prefixed by `&#`:

```
(xexpr->string '(elements () (INTEGER-CONSTANT () 9)))
=> "<elements><INTEGER-CONSTANT>&#9;</INTEGER-CONSTANT></elements>"
```

Just put quotes around the number:

```
(xexpr->string '(elements () (INTEGER-CONSTANT () "8")))
=>"<elements><INTEGER-CONSTANT>8</INTEGER-CONSTANT></elements>"
(xexpr->string '(elements () (INTEGER-CONSTANT () "9")))
"<elements><INTEGER-CONSTANT>9</INTEGER-CONSTANT></elements>"
```

Comment: OK, it works, but it still strange for me. Did the 8 taken like char no. 8?

Comment: Yes. And according to http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#charsets the character 8 is not allowed in an XML document. The character 9 is (probably because it's the TAB character).

Comment: Generally in an `xexpr` you want to express values as strings, including numeric values. A number is interpreted as a character code. Likewise a symbol is interpreted as a character entity, e.g. `(xexpr->string '(p () "AT" amp "T"))` will be `"<p>AT&amp;T</p>"`.